# How to switch HTML page in Python with Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-urls

Template :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'edit' %}">Edit</a>ù
```

views.py:

```
def edit(request):
    return render(request, "edit.html")
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/create", views.create, name="create"),
    path("wiki/edit", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("wiki/<str:name>", views.entry, name="entry"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("save", views.save, name="save"),
    path("random", views.random, name="random"),
]
```

[image]

I would like simply to switch from an HTML page on another, but the function gives me this error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /wiki/edit

   edit.html
```

But the template exist, I created it. I tryed a lot of changes but all of them gives me error. Thank you.

Comment: Please show template folder structure.

Comment: @Lewis I added an image of the template folder.

Comment: Try using `return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html")` in your views

Comment: Please could you sign select as right answer, to mark this question as closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Application name needs to be referenced in the template name.

Like so:

```py
return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html")
```